# Replacing blocks with /setblock won't work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am using version 1.8.9.

So I used this command:

```
/setblock ~ ~6 ~ air 0 replace end_portal
```

And it worked perfectly fine, but when I swapped the two blocks with this command,

```
/setblock ~ ~6 ~ end_portal 0 replace air
```

It didn't work, and displayed the error:

```
Data tag parsing failed invalid tag encountered expected '{' as first char.
```

Does anyone know what is causing this?

Answer (score 4):

`setblock` cannot `replace` specific blocks like that; only `fill` can. Putting `replace` in a `setblock` command just tells the command not to drop any items from the replaced block. Your first command appears to be working, but it's actually ignoring the `end_portal` bit completely. It'd set any block to air: dirt, stone, anything.

The correct syntax for the `setblock` command is
`/setblock <x> <y> <z> <block> [dataValue|state] [oldBlockHandling] [dataTag]`

So your original command,
`/setblock ~ ~6 ~ air 0 replace end_portal`

should reasonably fail for two reasons:

1. The `air` block does not support NBT
2. `end_portal` not valid NBT data

What actually happens is that Minecraft says, "Well, `air` doesn't support NBT, so I'll just ignore this bit that should be NBT." Your command, therefore, is equivalent to
`/setblock ~ ~6 ~ air 0 replace`

But with your second command, Minecraft says "The `end_portal` block *does* support NBT, so let's parse this--hey! This isn't valid NBT!" and throws an error.

---

If you're using command blocks, you can test for the air block explicitly, and then only set the end portal if the test succeeded:

```
   /testforblock <x> <y> <z> air
C: /setblock <x> <y> <z> end_portal
```

Where `C:` indicates a conditional command block.

Comment: Alternatively you could just fill one block: `/fill ~ ~6 ~ ~ ~6 ~ air 0 replace end_portal`

Answer (score 1):

Or just use /fill ~ ~-6 ~ ~ ~-6 ~
fill only that one block